# How to implement the General Tree data structure with arbitrary number of nodes in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I am googling from the last two days to find complete C++ implementation of general tree but I only found the binary tree implementation that is why I am posting my question here.

I have added the following code but now I am confused how to complete it:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
  int data;
  vector<node> children;
};

class Tree
{
  TreeNode *root, *temp, *newN;
  public:

  Tree(){ root=NULL; }

  void addNode(int value)
{
  newN= new node;
  newN->data = value;
  if(root == NULL)
  root = newN;

}


};

void main()
{
  Tree root;
  root.addNode(10);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, together with a description of your problems with it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I really need this question to be answered, even if it does not properly fulfill the rules but please kindly answer it, I will learn how to ask questions time to time as I am new now. I beg a pardon for this.

Comment: A hint: You need to have a container of *pointers* to children. And always build your code *often*, fixing the errors that the compiler is telling you. And if possible, please try to get a compiler from this side of the millennium (that support *standard* C++, even if it's the first 1998 standard).

Comment: You might be interested in the [left child right sibling representation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/left-child-right-sibling-representation-tree/). You might also find what you're looking for by searching for "multiway tree" or "k-ary tree".

Comment: @JimMischel : I am interested in the n-ary tree where there are arbitrary number of child nodes for every node in the tree.

Comment: Well then, there you go. I gave you the search terms. Fire up your favorite search engine, do a little research, and start coding.

Answer (score 0):

To build the tree you need a function that takes two input:

1. Reference to an existing node in the tree that will be the parent of the new node in tree
2. Value of the new node